# My webpage doesn't display the table I'm trying to print out

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, cs50

This is a question referring to lab 9 in CS50X. I didn't get an answer on Ed Discussion.
In my code, I have a database with its elements. I'm trying to print out each row of that database in a tabular for in an HTML file using Jinja syntax. I have double checked and made sure that the elements of the database exist by printing them out on Python. Nothing seems to be happening on my webpage, though.
So I simply have to print it out. I'm using Jinja syntax and Flask, and I'm new to it, which could explain any rookie mistakes.
Here's my flask code:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        bname = request.form.get("name")
        bday = request.form.get("day")
        bmonth = request.form.get("month")

        db.execute("INSERT INTO birthdays (name, month, day) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", bname, bmonth, bday)

        return redirect("/")

    else:

        tableau = db.execute("SELECT * FROM birthdays")

        return render_template("index.html")
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="section">

                <h2>All Birthdays</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Birthday</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for row in tableau %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{row['name']}}</td>
                            <td>{{row['month']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I'm basically just trying to print each row of my database into each row of a table on HTML using Jinja syntax. My database has all the elements needed. I'm new to Flask and Jinja, and it would explain any rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `render_template`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.render_template).

It takes two arguments:

> - template_name_or_list (Union[str, List[str]]) – the name of the template to be rendered, or an iterable with template names the first one existing will be rendered
> - context (Any) – the variables that should be available in the context of the template.

But you are only passing it one:

> ```
> render_template("index.html")
> ```

Since you haven’t passed it a `context`, there are no variables available inside it, so `tableau` does not exist.